# ngClass condition is not working on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ng-class

I am trying to implement  [ngClass] based on different conditions here is my

```
condition
 [ngClass]="{'validator':lang.VideoURL!=null, 'labeltitle': lang.VideoURL==null}"
```

but when value of **lang.VideoURL** is null then **labeltitle** class is not applying on the page  and by default validator class is applying when value of lang.VideoURL is null

Comment: try this: `[ngClass]="{'validator':lang.VideoURL, 'labeltitle': !lang.VideoURL}"`

Comment: FYI my guess is that your logic in the condition is actually fine, but that your value of lang.VideoURL is not null but is probably undefined, which would cause the behavior you are explaining above.  This is also why the suggested answers are working, since they are not concerned with null or undefined, and are instead focused on false or true (both null and undefined will be considered false, so either works then)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
[ngClass]="lang.VideoURL ? 'validator' : 'labeltitle'"
```

Answer (score 3):

@porgo's answer is also correct but if you have more condition to check you can try like this.

```
[ngClass]="[lang.VideoURL != null: 'validator', lang.VideoURL == null: 'labeltitle']"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is class property binding shown here https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-targets.  This is helpful if you have more than one class that could be valid at a time but which are all conditional.

```
[class.validator]="lang.VideoURL" [class.labeltitle]="!lang.VideoURL"
```

Comment: IMO, this is the best way to do this.  It's much more clear and you only have one piece of logic per class name & angular attribute

Comment: yup, it's definitely my favorite way, since working on a team I want things to be instantly understood by anyone who is reading the code.  This is the most direct way IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

this is the way to use ngClass multi-condition.

```
 [ngClass]="{'first-class': condition1,'second-class': condition2}"
```